# F# error FS0193 (VS 2010) : The type 'WebRequest' is not compatible with the type 'HttpWebRequest'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

Recently I work in a CBIR student project. And we need lots of photos of world landmarks. I've found this Flickr Crawler project ([blog](http://fdatamining.blogspot.tw/2010/07/f-async-workflow-application-flickr.html), [sourcecode](http://fdatamining.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8979#148637)) written in F#. But I encounter an error when building it in my Visual Studio 2010:

error FS0193: 
Type constraint mismatch. The type WebRequest is not compatible with type HttpWebRequest . The type 'WebRequest' is not compatible with the type 'HttpWebRequest'

Line 2 (let req=...) is where the error happens:

```
let downloadUrl(url:string) = 
    let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) :> HttpWebRequest
    req.UserAgent <- "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
    req.Method <- "GET";
    req.AllowAutoRedirect <- true;
    req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections <- 4;
    req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections <- 4;
    let resp = req.GetResponse()
    let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    reader.ReadToEnd()
```

I did not learn F# before so I am not familiar with F#. What does this error message suggest and how do I solve it?

Comment: Could you post the full error message (with line number etc) and a snippet of the relevant code so that your question may be helpful to anyone visiting in the future in case the linked code changes (and also so that people don't have to download and compile a huge chunk of code to find the error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error was quite small.  The `:>` operator will only perform casts which are known to succeed at compile time and so won't cast from `HttpWebRequest.Create(url)` to `HttpWebRequest` as this actually returns a `WebRequest`.  As a reult you need to use

```
 let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
```

instead to allow for casting in the other direction in the inheritance tree.  The difference is that casts made by `:?>` may fail at run time (but shouldn't in this case as all urls should be http)